# Is there any use for a Google Home Mini without WiFi?

Tags: google-home

The WiFi of my Google Home Mini is dead after 1 year or so of use.  Yes, I have tried everything to verify this (factory reset, Wi-Fi with password, without password, different bands, two totally different Wi-Fi networks).

I hate to use Google Home Mini only as a book weight now.  Are there any other ways to use it? For example, is there a way to use its speaker which is still decent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3rd party Ethernet adapters (and Google used to do one for [Chromecasts](https://store.google.com/product/ethernet_adapter_for_chromecast) that I think should work) which assuming it's just the Wifi that is broken will allow you to wire the Mini into the local Lan.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Google Home Mini has only one port - the USB mini for power.  How can I wire it to a router?  Do I need to disassemble it?

Comment: The adapters supply power and data over the mini usb port

Comment: Got it. I assume you meant something like this:https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Adapter-All-New-Chromecast-100Mbps/dp/B07M5X9795/ref=asc_df_B07M5X9795/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=385191927323&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=11800036393870298204&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001929&hvtargid=pla-827868400289&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=82240853001&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=385191927323&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=11800036393870298204&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001929&hvtargid=pla-827868400289

Comment: I have just ordered one. I will come back to confirm after using it.

Comment: Still waiting for you to come back and confirm ...

Comment: I have just used an adapter bought from eBay (https://www.ebay.com/itm/Ethernet-Adapter-for-Amazon-Fire-TV-Google-Home-Mini-Chromecast-Ultra-2-1/264935302014?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) as the answer suggests.  It works perfectly. Thank you again.